# Azure Machine Learning Studio back up

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Do you know how back up machine learning models in Azure Machine Learning Studio in case of idle time when subscription is not bought. I would preferably back those models in Azure DB/DWH on other accounts/instances of Azure. Is it actually possible to copy models' flow to another locations or share it with other users?
I would appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to export your experiments in Azure Machine Learning Studio to local as a file or other type resources. There seems not to be any way for doing this on Azure offical sites, but I searched a third party tool named [`azuremlps`](https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps) which is a PowerShell module for Azure ML Studio from a MSFT. You can try to use the cmdlet [`Export-AmlExperimentGraph`](http://Export-AmlExperimentGraph) to export a specific Experiment graph to a file in JSON format.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to backup the experiments you've created directly. You can share the models with other users in two way.

1. Share publicly through the gallery. All can see the experiment you've created.
2. Share privately allows you to share an experiment with the people only have the link for your published experiment.

Use 'Publish to gallery' operation as shown in below for the above task.

[image]